# Relationship between linear dependence/convergence

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, limits, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

Suppose I have two convergent sequences ${\{X_m}\}$ and ${\{Y_m}\}$ with limits $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How do I go about proving/disproving the following:

a) If for every $m$, the two vectors $X_m$ and $Y_m$ are linearly dependent, then $X$ and $Y$ are linearly dependent.

Similarly, b) If for every $m$, the two vectors $X_m$ and $Y_m$ are linearly independent, then $X$ and $Y$ are linearly independent.

Would the following work for b?

Say b is false. Let $X_m = {\{1/m,sin(m)/m}\}$, and $Y_m = {\{sin(m)/m,1/m}\}$, then the vectors $X_m$ and $Y_m$ are always linearly independent and both sequences converge to $(0,0)$, thus they're dependent.

Comment: There's a much simpler counterexample to b $X_m = (1,1/m)$, $Y_m = (1,-1/m)$.

Comment: So (b) is false.  But for (a) you have $a_mX_m + b_mY_m=0$ for all $m$, for some nonzero vectors $(a_m, b_m) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.  You can normalize the vectors $(a_m,  b_m)$ and then use a Bolzano-Wierstrass-type argument.

Comment: For b, if $X_m\rightarrow X=0$ then $c_1.X+c_2.Y=0$ gives $c_1\neq 0$.